# PyOpenCL with multiprocessing INVALID_DEVICE

Tags: opencl, nvidia

My use case is a main process that compiles a bunch of Open CL kernels.   Later in the program several subprocesses are forked and will execute one or more of the kernels. For some reason the subprocesses have device errors.

I have determined the problem has nothing to do with compilation and have reproduced it with the following simple script:

```
import multiprocessing
import pyopencl as cl

def printme():
    platforms = cl.get_platforms()
    for p in platforms:
        print 75*'!'
        print p
        print 75*':'

printme()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target = printme)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Seems to be tied to the NVIDIA OpenCL implementation and not related to PyOpenCL as I initially thought.  The same problem occurs with the example below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>

#define CHECK(A) if ((status = A) != 0) { \
        fprintf(stderr, "failed status %d at line %d\n", status, __LINE__); \
        exit(1); \
}

static void
runit() {
        int i;
        cl_int status;
        cl_platform_id *platforms;
        cl_uint num_platforms;
        cl_uint num_devices;

        CHECK(clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &num_platforms));
        if (num_platforms == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "no platforms\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        platforms = malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id)*num_platforms);
        CHECK(clGetPlatformIDs(num_platforms, platforms, NULL));


        CHECK(clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL,
                                &num_devices));

        free(platforms);
}

int main(void) {
  runit();

  if (fork() == 0) {
      runit();
  }
  else {
      wait(NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Exits with failed status = -33 (Invalid Device).  Seems that there is some stored state inside the implementation.  Note this is running from an NVidia driver.

Comment: I suspect most OpenCL implementations are not `fork()` safe. You will need to re-enumerate the devices and create new contexts in the child processes.

Comment: I think you are right about not being fork() safe.  There is no way to re-enumerate though because it seems the implementation is keeping some stored state that is tied to the parent process.  If only there was some way to clear out the stored state.